# Semantic Media Wiki action=purge alternatives and automation

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I'm having an issue where pages with #ask queries aren't updating after updating content on other pages. The only way to get them to update seems to be using action=purge. Is there a maintenance script that will preform this across all pages? Which variables can I use to reduce the amount of time a page is cached? I'm having trouble determining which cache's I need to adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is documented on the Semantic MediaWiki page at https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Embedded_query_update. The documentation should explain fairly well which caches are relevant and what kind of configurtion you need.